# how to load a page from different domain into div without using iframe and after cors is enabling from server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am developing a live chat for website. In which I develop a client.aspx page there whole chat part is there that is hosted into different domain and I am loading that chat page into some other website by these method into div

```
$('#onlinechat').live('click', function (e) {
    $("#includedContent").load('http://localhost:53398/client.aspx?companyname=' + company + ';' + sessionid + ';' + ipAddress);
});

<div id="includedContent" class="chat_window"></div>
```

I know its problem of CORS same origin policy but i enabled from server still its not able to load that page into my website i don't want load into iframe is their any way load without affecting jquery file.

Comment: Can you GET the file on its own by typing the URL in a new browser tab? What does the network tab in the dev tools tell you?

Comment: Where are you using Iframe?

Comment: i don't want into new tab to load that page??? and i want to load that page into div